# 502 Bad Gateway with PHP7 and Nginx 1.9.9

Tags: php, nginx

I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error with `PHP7` and `nginx 1.9.9` installed on Ubuntu `14.04` when I try to access any `.php` files. `.html` files load as expected.

I've updated the `default.conf` to:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I've updated `php.ini` with `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0` and then rebooted the server, and am still getting the `502` error with all `.php` files. I have checked to ensure `php7.0-fpm.sock` is installed and in the proper location.

This is the error I'm getting from the nginx log `2016/01/19 19:14:54 [error] 1466#1466: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/xmlrpc.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 85.159.237.13, server: localhost, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", host: "my.ip.address"`

I've searched for the answer for quite a while and I'm out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Checked error logs and all? And is this in `/nginx/site-enabled`?

Comment: for log files...both nginx and php would be useful

Comment: `/nginx/site-enabled` wasn't setup by default in 1.9.9 so I checked the `default.conf` in `etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and it has the line `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`   I'll check the logs in a bit and post what they say.

Comment: i think i had this issue one and it turned out to be that the pathway expected from nginx was not the pathway that was aliased when i checked my php configs. you might check what your php directories are in /etc/ and confirm what socket's getting listened to there (if you haven't already).

if memory serves, in my case, i was referencing a version, like you, in my nginx config, but my fpm setup in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf has something different. when i made these match, things started to resolve

Comment: Both the `default.conf` and `www.conf` reference the same path for `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly because your nginx and php7.0-fpm were not run under the same user. Edit nginx.conf and change "user nginx" to "user www-data" 
By the way, "client: 85.159.237.13", that was a script boy, I think.